# Create Dictionary of Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am trying to copy a dictionary of dictionary (person_profile) into a new dictionary of dictionary (person_info) because I am trying to merge two different dictionaries (person_profile and person_attribute into person_info) with not necessarily same length and key value. Below are my code (I changed the variable just to make it sound more simple):

```
for person in person_profile:
    person_info.update({ 
        person.id :
       {'name' : person.name, 'age' : person.age} 
    })

# And call person_attribute again
for person in person_attribute:
    person_info.update({ 
        person.id :
       {'occupation' : person.occupation, 'gender' : person.gender} 
    })
```

However above method seems to create a set instead of dictionary. I couldn't find how to do so in other articles. What is a recommended approach to this problem?

== ANSWERED

```
for person in person_profile:
    person_info[person.id] = {'name' : person.name, 'age' : person.age}

for person in person_attribute:
    person_info[person.id].update({
        'occupation' : person.occupation, 'gender' : person.gender
    })
```

Comment: Your code is not creating a set, no. You *are* replacing the dictionary keyed on `person.id` entirely each time in that second loop.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample input (a starting value for `person_info`, and dummy `person_profile` and `person_attribute` lists), as well as expected `person_info` output.

Comment: Also show us the actual output you got instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The problem was that I was replacing the dictionary with the second dictionary. Thank you so much!

Comment: In future, add a [mcve] (including the input and output I mentioned) so we can help you without having to make (educated) guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually replacing `person.name` and `person.age` with `person.occupation` and `person.gender` for each person in the list instead of merging them.

Based on your code, I would do the following in order to put both of those properties in a dictionary:

```
>>> import collections
>>> person_info = collections.defaultdict(dict)

>>> for person in person_profile:
...     person_info[person.id].update({'name': person.name, 'age': person.age}) 

>>> for person in person_attribute:
...     person_info[person.id].update({'occupation': person.occupation, 'gender': person.gender})
```

Comment: This answer worked except that for the first iteration of dictionary update (person_profile), I had to assign a dictionary to person_info[person.id] (person_info[person.id] = {'name' : person.name, 'age' : person.age}) if not the dictionary was not defined. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @seokhoonlee You don't have to do that. `defaultdict` already creates an empty dictionary for a missing key behind the scenes and put it into `person_info` when you access it so you never get `KeyError` exception. Try something like `print(person_info["lorem ipsum"])` and see what happens.

Comment: oh i thought you were just initializing the dictionary. Thanks tons!

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to do is the following.
Your code is not working like `set` but simply replaces a `dict` with other `dict` if `person_id` matches.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id, name, age, occupation, gender):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.occupation = occupation
        self.gender = gender


person_info = dict()
person_profile = [Person(1, 'Jack', 17, '---', '---'), Person(2, 'Jane', 19, '---', '---')]
for person in person_profile:
    person_info.update({
        person.id :
       {'name' : person.name, 'age' : person.age}
    })

person_attribute = [Person(1, '---', '---', 'Senetor', 'Male'), Person(2, '---', '---', 'Nurse', 'Female')]
for person in person_attribute:
    data = person_info.get(person.id)
    attribute_dict = {'occupation' : person.occupation, 'gender' : person.gender}

    if data:
        data.update(attribute_dict)
    else:
        data = attribute_dict
print(person_info)
```